# Issuing SSL certificate for remote desktop without FQDN

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop, rdp

I am using a VPS which doesn't host any website, or domain name. I need to remote-access that VPS using Remote Desktop.

To be sure no one is eavesdropping my traffic with the VPS, I need to setup an SSL certificate on the server. But the first thing they ask is a Fully Qualified Domain Name. Is there any way I can skip creating a domain that I don't need in order to buy the certificate? Since I will only need it for my remote desktop sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the facts:

1- You need a fully qualified domain name to request a certificate.
2- You don't have to bind the domain to the server in case you don't want to.
3- After installing the certificate, if the server address is not the same as the domain associated with the certificate, you will get a warning that the address doesn't match the certificate.

Hope this will help anyone who has case similar to mine.